# Changing Excel data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, excel, internet-explorer

I am working on a tool where I control a Excel sheet using JavaScript.

Here is a requirement that, I need to change the Excel cell data. 
I was doing something like this:

**1. Open Excel as:**

```
excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

excel.Visible = false;
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

workBook = excel.WorkBooks.open("c:\\excel.xls");

workSheet = workBook.Worksheets("Work_sheet_1");
```

**2. Make change as:**

```
WorkSheet.Cells(10,20).value = "10";
console.log("Value stored in excel is: "+WorkSheet.Cells(10,20).value);
```

**3. Close as:**

```
excelWorkbook.save(); 
excelWorkbook.Close(true, "c:\\excel.xls").    
workBook.Close(false);
    excel.application.quit();
    excel = null;
```

I run it in browser, and I get log as:

```
Value stored in excel is: 10
```

Now whenever I make any change in Excel through JavaScript, I can always see the correct log report, But in excel, this changes are either **saved at a delayed of 2 - 3 min**, or **never saves any change**. this seems a kind of weird. Over that, when try to open the excel sheet manually from folder, it gives **Edit-mode Lock Pop-up**.

Can anyone tell me where am I heading wrong?

Comment: change `workBook.Close(false);` to `workBook.Close(true);` to save changes in workbook

Comment: @simoco No dude! Never worked. did the same.

Comment: as far as I know, JavaScript is case sensitive, so since you defined `workSheet = workBook.Worksheets("Work_sheet_1");` (starting from `w` but not `W`) than also use `workSheet .Cells(10,20).value = "10";` instead `WorkSheet.Cells(10,20).value = "10";` and save changes: `workBook.Close(true);`:)

Comment: Just to correct you a bit. **true is for save pop-out** and **false is for direct saving**.

Comment: btw, did `workSheet .Cells(10,20).value = "10";` solve your problem?

Comment: got the solution Dude. added 1 line in Step 1: `excel.DisplayAlerts = false;` and added this in step 3: 'excelWorkbook.save();` `excelWorkbook.Close(true, "c:\\excel.xls")`.